# Is there a way to explicitly set colors for embeddings in Tensorboard Embedding Projector?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, word-embedding

I have embeddings that represent a hierarchical group structure.  I'd like to be able to set my own color scheme for visualization in the embedding projector (rather than letting the embedding projector choose colors for me).

I want to capture the hierarchical structure of my data. For example, I'd like class `A1`, `A2`, `A3` to all be shades of one color and class `B1`, `B2`, `B3` to be shades of another color.